# Can we find solution for this equation?

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$ be a vector which $a_i∈Z$(are integers). I'd like to find a way to check if they satisfies in the following equations or not?

$a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=4a_0$

$a_1a_0+a_0a_1+a_3a_2+a_2a_3=4a_1$

$a_2a_0+a_3a_1+a_0a_2+a_1a_3=4a_2$

$a_3a_0+a_2a_1+a_1a_2+a_0a_3=4a_3$

In each line $a_i$ multiply $a_j$ which $i \oplus j=n$ which $\oplus$ means exclusive-or.
Clearly it has a matrix representation too. Of course it continues  for equations till $a_{2^n-1}$

I'm searching for some necessary conditions on $a_i$'s which satisfy in this.
Do you know if it is a famous equation or something which has a predetermined response. Are there any condition on these integers to satisfy in these?If I get these integers I can find out if they satisfy?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Did you mean $a_2^3$ in the first equation or did you intend $a_3^2$?  Why write $a_1a_0+a_0a_1$ instead of $2a_0a_1$?

Answer (score 1):

This system can be easily solved by using [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) over the complex numbers. As it turns out, all $16$ solutions are integral:
$$
(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,0,0,0),(4,0,0,0),(2,2,0,0),(2,-2,0,0),(2,0,2,0),
$$

$$
(2,0,-2,0), (2,0,0,-2), (2,0,0,2), (1,-1,-1,1),(1,1,1,1),(3,1,-1,1),
$$

$$
 (3,-1,1,1), (1,1,-1,-1), (1,-1,1,-1), (3,-1,-1,-1),  (3,1,1,-1).
$$ 
Of course, this can be shown directly, without using Buchberger's algorithm.